# Using isset when variable is not called in code

Tags: php, variables, if-statement, isset

I am editing the wp-login.php which was created by a plugin for WordPress. I'd like to send a custom text field to a custom table on the registration page, but the plugin is using the same php file for both the login and registration page. So on the login page the insert to the table is failing.

I tried using isset ($POST_) for address1 which is what I am trying to insert to the custom table. But since the login page does not have the field value, it errors trying to find address1. Is Address1 is not called in the code, does isset fail because there was never an address1 called during the script? Is there a workaround when address1 is not defined?

Answer (score 0):

If your code uses `isset ($POST_)` as described in your question then that could be your issue because the correct syntax is `$_POST` not `$POST_`...